# O que é um DataSet e qual sua função?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Criando minhas primeiras aplicações com banco de dados (SQL Server), faço a conexão passando minha string e utilizando a classe SQLCommand para passar a query.

Mas pesquisando em outros sites, vejo que o acesso ao banco é feito via DataSet.

O que seria um DataSet e qual sua função?

Comment: o google vai te retornar diversos tutorias sobre o assunto, aqui no SO você pode fazer uma pergunta mais específica sobre código, como por exemplo "Como preencher o DataSet através de uma procedure?", supondo que você já tentou algumas coisas e pode mostrar seu código e onde está com dúvida. Só pra esclarecer, DataSet não é usado pra acesso ao banco, ele armazena dados

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Primeiramente você deve entender o que é o ADO.NET. Ele é uma camada de acesso entre algum armazém de dados (não se limita ao banco de dados) e a sua aplicação .NET. No seu caso, para acessar as informações do SQL Server existe a camada do ADO.NET que vai fazer o intermédio entre o seu banco e sua aplicação. O SQLCommand que você citou é uma classe da arquitetura do ADO.NET que ajuda nesse processo.

O DataSet **não serve para fazer acesso ao banco de dados**. O DataSet abstrai esses dados externo ao framework quando estiverem em memória, sendo ele **independente da fonte de dados**. Para exemplificar, quando você faz uma requisição ao banco de dados:

```
SELECT * FROM PESSOAS WHERE PESSOAS.NAME LIKE 'COLETTA'
```

O banco de dados vai processar esse SQL, e quando chegar na camada de acesso de dados, o mesmo vai armazenar essa informação em memória, como exemplo em um DataSet ou DataReader, de acordo com a implementação.

Com a estrutura do DataSet, eu posso manipular meus dados em memória com seus DataTable e DataRelation, igual a estrutura relacional dos bancos de dados. Exemplo:

```
//criando o dataSet;
DataSet exemplo = new DataSet("EXEMPLO");  
DataTable peopleTable = exemplo.Tables.Add("PESSOAS");
peopleTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
```

Perceba nesse exemplo que eu criei uma tabela chamada PESSOAS com uma coluna chamada Name. Agora eu posso adicionar registros dentro dessa estrutura:

```
DataRow myRow = exemplo.Tables["PESSOAS"].NewRow();
myRow["Name"] = "COLETTA";
```

O meu exemplo é realmente simples e não teria muita utilidade, mas a ideia é exemplificar como a estrutura é criada. Criando essas estruturas, você poderia inserir dentro do seu banco de dados Sql Server utilizando o `SqlDataAdapter.Update(exemplo);`

Answer (score 4):

O [*dataset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_set), como o nome diz, é apenas um conjunto de dados. Ele é finito e tem uma função e característica específica.

Usamos ele para tratar dados que vieram do banco de dados através de alguma consulta, muitas vezes através de um comando SQL, então vem as colunas e e linhas das tabelas que você determinar. Tudo o que importa para o que você fará naquela operação está no *dataset* montado pela consulta feita.

Um *dataset* pode ser montado manualmente ou através de um *framework*, como o Entity Framework que é muito usado com o .NET.

O ADO.NET ter seu próprio [`DataSet`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Ele é considerado mais ou menos obsoleto. Não que não possa ser usado e não tenha utilidade, mas na maioria dos casos se usar ele fortemente fica muito pesado que compensa usar o EF.

Quando precisa fazer algo mais simples costuma ser mais interessante ter apenas um [`DataReader`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ([específico para o SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)) e depois gravar na mão o que precisa, de uma forma chamada desconectada, talvez através de um [`DataAdapter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Então ele é uma abstração para acessar dados que vieram de um fonte de dados, provavelmente um banco de dados, que pode ser o SQL Server, assim ele acessa os dados do banco de forma indireta através de um "espelho" na memória.

Eu evitaria seu uso a não ser que faça muito sentido. Há quem goste.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).